# My filter app with the following lines of code to produce blur effect on images is giving runtime error in C

Tags: c, image, blur, cs50

I am using a box blur algorithm to create a blur filter on images using C. However I am getting some runtime error even though my program compiles successfully. I get the following error.

> helpers.c:143:72: runtime error: index 600 out of bounds for type
>   'RGBTRIPLE [width]'   helpers.c:143:158: runtime error: index 600 out
>   of bounds for type 'RGBTRIPLE [width]'   helpers.c:146:76: runtime
>   error: index 600 out of bounds for type 'RGBTRIPLE [width]'
>   helpers.c:146:166: runtime error: index 600 out of bounds for type
>   'RGBTRIPLE [width]'   helpers.c:149:74: runtime error: index 600 out
>   of bounds for type 'RGBTRIPLE [width]'   helpers.c:149:162: runtime
>   error: index 600 out of bounds for type 'RGBTRIPLE [width]'
>   helpers.c:207:72: runtime error: index 600 out of bounds for type
>   'RGBTRIPLE [width]'   helpers.c:207:158: runtime error: index 600 out
>   of bounds for type 'RGBTRIPLE [width]'   helpers.c:207:334: runtime
>   error: index 600 out of bounds for type 'RGBTRIPLE [width]'
>   helpers.c:210:76: runtime error: index 600 out of bounds for type
>   'RGBTRIPLE [width]'   helpers.c:210:166: runtime error: index 600 out
>   of bounds for type 'RGBTRIPLE [width]'   helpers.c:210:350: runtime
>   error: index 600 out of bounds for type 'RGBTRIPLE [width]'
>   helpers.c:213:74: runtime error: index 600 out of bounds for type
>   'RGBTRIPLE [width]'   helpers.c:213:342: runtime error: index 600 out
>   of bounds for type 'RGBTRIPLE [width]'

The error does complain of the following lines of code:

```
 else
            {
                red_sum = image[image_row][image_column].rgbtRed + image[image_row][image_column+1].rgbtRed + image[image_row+1][image_column].rgbtRed + image[image_row+1][image_column+1].rgbtRed + image[image_row+1][image_column-1].rgbtRed + image[image_row][image_column-1].rgbtRed;
                red_average = my_average(6.0, red_sum);

                green_sum = image[image_row][image_column].rgbtGreen + image[image_row][image_column+1].rgbtGreen + image[image_row+1][image_column].rgbtGreen + image[image_row+1][image_column+1].rgbtGreen + image[image_row+1][image_column-1].rgbtGreen + image[image_row][image_column-1].rgbtGreen;
                green_average = my_average(6.0, green_sum);

                blue_sum = image[image_row][image_column].rgbtBlue + image[image_row][image_column+1].rgbtBlue + image[image_row+1][image_column].rgbtBlue + image[image_row+1][image_column+1].rgbtBlue + image[image_row+1][image_column-1].rgbtBlue + image[image_row][image_column-1].rgbtBlue;
                blue_average = my_average(6.0, blue_sum);

                image_copy[image_row][image_column].rgbtRed = red_average;
                image_copy[image_row][image_column].rgbtGreen = green_average;
                image_copy[image_row][image_column].rgbtBlue = blue_average;
            }
```

and here:

```
else
    {
        if (image_column != 0 && image_column != column_end)
        {
            red_sum = image[image_row][image_column].rgbtRed + image[image_row][image_column+1].rgbtRed + image[image_row-1][image_column].rgbtRed + image[image_row-1][image_column+1].rgbtRed + image[image_row-1][image_column-1].rgbtRed + image[image_row][image_column-1].rgbtRed + image[image_row+1][image_column].rgbtRed + image[image_row+1][image_column+1].rgbtRed + image[image_row+1][image_column-1].rgbtRed;
            red_average = my_average(9.0, red_sum);

            green_sum = image[image_row][image_column].rgbtGreen + image[image_row][image_column+1].rgbtGreen + image[image_row-1][image_column].rgbtGreen + image[image_row-1][image_column+1].rgbtGreen + image[image_row-1][image_column-1].rgbtGreen + image[image_row][image_column-1].rgbtGreen + image[image_row+1][image_column].rgbtGreen + image[image_row+1][image_column+1].rgbtGreen + image[image_row+1][image_column-1].rgbtGreen;
            green_average = my_average(9.0, green_sum);

            blue_sum = image[image_row][image_column].rgbtBlue + image[image_row][image_column+1].rgbtBlue + image[image_row-1][image_column].rgbtBlue + image[image_row+1][image_column-1].rgbtBlue + image[image_row-1][image_column-1].rgbtBlue + image[image_row][image_column-1].rgbtBlue + image[image_row+1][image_column].rgbtBlue + image[image_row+1][image_column+1].rgbtBlue + image[image_row+1][image_column-1].rgbtBlue;
            blue_average = my_average(9.0, blue_sum);

            image_copy[image_row][image_column].rgbtRed = red_average;
            image_copy[image_row][image_column].rgbtGreen = green_average;
            image_copy[image_row][image_column].rgbtBlue = blue_average;
        }
```

Most of which deals with handling the middle and edges of the image being processed.

Edit:
Here is the definition of my loops:

```
    for (int image_row = 0; image_row < height; image_row++)
{
    int row_end = image_row - 1;
    for (int image_column = 0; image_column < width; image_column++)
    {
        int column_end = image_column-1;
        if (image_row == 0)
        {
            if (image_column == 0)
            {
                red_sum = image[image_row][image_column].rgbtRed + image[image_row][image_column+1].rgbtRed + image[image_row+1][image_column].rgbtRed + image[image_row+1][image_column+1].rgbtRed;
                red_average = my_average(4.0, red_sum);

                green_sum = image[image_row][image_column].rgbtGreen + image[image_row][image_column+1].rgbtGreen + image[image_row+1][image_column].rgbtGreen + image[image_row+1][image_column+1].rgbtGreen;
                green_average = my_average(4.0, green_sum);

                blue_sum = image[image_row][image_column].rgbtBlue + image[image_row][image_column+1].rgbtBlue + image[image_row+1][image_column].rgbtBlue + image[image_row+1][image_column+1].rgbtBlue;
                blue_average = my_average(4.0, blue_sum);

                image_copy[image_row][image_column].rgbtRed = red_average;
                image_copy[image_row][image_column].rgbtGreen = green_average;
                image_copy[image_row][image_column].rgbtBlue = blue_average;
            }
            else if (image_column == column_end)
            {
                red_sum = image[image_row][column_end].rgbtRed + image[image_row][column_end-1].rgbtRed + image[image_row+1][column_end].rgbtRed + image[image_row+1][column_end-1].rgbtRed;
                red_average = my_average(4.0, red_sum);

                green_sum = image[image_row][column_end].rgbtGreen + image[image_row][column_end-1].rgbtGreen + image[image_row+1][column_end].rgbtGreen + image[image_row+1][column_end-1].rgbtGreen;
                green_average = my_average(4.0, green_sum);

                blue_sum = image[image_row][column_end].rgbtBlue + image[image_row][column_end-1].rgbtBlue + image[image_row+1][column_end].rgbtBlue + image[image_row+1][column_end-1].rgbtBlue;
                blue_average = my_average(4.0, blue_sum);

                image_copy[image_row][image_column].rgbtRed = red_average;
                image_copy[image_row][image_column].rgbtGreen = green_average;
                image_copy[image_row][image_column].rgbtBlue = blue_average;
            }
            else
            {
                red_sum = image[image_row][image_column].rgbtRed + image[image_row][image_column+1].rgbtRed + image[image_row+1][image_column].rgbtRed + image[image_row+1][image_column+1].rgbtRed + image[image_row+1][image_column-1].rgbtRed + image[image_row][image_column-1].rgbtRed;
                red_average = my_average(6.0, red_sum);

                green_sum = image[image_row][image_column].rgbtGreen + image[image_row][image_column+1].rgbtGreen + image[image_row+1][image_column].rgbtGreen + image[image_row+1][image_column+1].rgbtGreen + image[image_row+1][image_column-1].rgbtGreen + image[image_row][image_column-1].rgbtGreen;
                green_average = my_average(6.0, green_sum);

                blue_sum = image[image_row][image_column].rgbtBlue + image[image_row][image_column+1].rgbtBlue + image[image_row+1][image_column].rgbtBlue + image[image_row+1][image_column+1].rgbtBlue + image[image_row+1][image_column-1].rgbtBlue + image[image_row][image_column-1].rgbtBlue;
                blue_average = my_average(6.0, blue_sum);

                image_copy[image_row][image_column].rgbtRed = red_average;
                image_copy[image_row][image_column].rgbtGreen = green_average;
                image_copy[image_row][image_column].rgbtBlue = blue_average;
            }
        }
        else if (image_row == row_end)
        {
            if (image_column == 0)
            {
                red_sum = image[image_row][image_column].rgbtRed + image[image_row][image_column+1].rgbtRed + image[image_row-1][image_column].rgbtRed + image[image_row-1][image_column+1].rgbtRed;
                red_average = my_average(4.0, red_sum);

                green_sum = image[image_row][image_column].rgbtGreen + image[image_row][image_column+1].rgbtGreen + image[image_row-1][image_column].rgbtGreen + image[image_row-1][image_column+1].rgbtGreen;
                green_average = my_average(4.0, green_sum);

                blue_sum = image[image_row][image_column].rgbtBlue + image[image_row][image_column+1].rgbtBlue + image[image_row-1][image_column].rgbtBlue + image[image_row-1][image_column+1].rgbtBlue;
                blue_average = my_average(4.0, blue_sum);

                image_copy[image_row][image_column].rgbtRed = red_average;
                image_copy[image_row][image_column].rgbtGreen = green_average;
                image_copy[image_row][image_column].rgbtBlue = blue_average;
            }
            else if (image_column == column_end)
            {
                red_sum = image[image_row][image_column].rgbtRed + image[image_row][image_column-1].rgbtRed + image[image_row-1][image_column].rgbtRed + image[image_row-1][image_column-1].rgbtRed;
                red_average = my_average(4.0, red_sum);

                green_sum = image[image_row][image_column].rgbtGreen + image[image_row][image_column-1].rgbtGreen + image[image_row-1][image_column].rgbtGreen + image[image_row-1][image_column-1].rgbtGreen;
                green_average = my_average(4.0, green_sum);

                blue_sum = image[image_row][image_column].rgbtBlue + image[image_row][image_column-1].rgbtBlue + image[image_row-1][image_column].rgbtBlue + image[image_row-1][image_column-1].rgbtBlue;
                blue_average = my_average(4.0, blue_sum);
                image_copy[image_row][image_column].rgbtRed = red_average;
                image_copy[image_row][image_column].rgbtGreen = green_average;
                image_copy[image_row][image_column].rgbtBlue = blue_average;
            }
            else
            {
                red_sum = image[image_row][image_column].rgbtRed + image[image_row][image_column+1].rgbtRed + image[image_row-1][image_column].rgbtRed + image[image_row-1][image_column+1].rgbtRed + image[image_row-1][image_column-1].rgbtRed + image[image_row][image_column-1].rgbtRed;
                red_average = my_average(6.0, red_sum);

                green_sum = image[image_row][image_column].rgbtGreen + image[image_row][image_column+1].rgbtGreen + image[image_row-1][image_column].rgbtGreen + image[image_row-1][image_column+1].rgbtGreen + image[image_row-1][image_column-1].rgbtGreen + image[image_row][image_column-1].rgbtGreen;
                green_average = my_average(6.0, green_sum);

                blue_sum = image[image_row][image_column].rgbtBlue + image[image_row][image_column+1].rgbtBlue + image[image_row-1][image_column].rgbtBlue + image[image_row+1][image_column-1].rgbtBlue + image[image_row-1][image_column-1].rgbtBlue + image[image_row][image_column-1].rgbtBlue;
                blue_average = my_average(6.0, blue_sum);
                image_copy[image_row][image_column].rgbtRed = red_average;
                image_copy[image_row][image_column].rgbtGreen = green_average;
                image_copy[image_row][image_column].rgbtBlue = blue_average;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (image_column != 0 && image_column != column_end)
            {
                red_sum = image[image_row][image_column].rgbtRed + image[image_row][image_column+1].rgbtRed + image[image_row-1][image_column].rgbtRed + image[image_row-1][image_column+1].rgbtRed + image[image_row-1][image_column-1].rgbtRed + image[image_row][image_column-1].rgbtRed + image[image_row+1][image_column].rgbtRed + image[image_row+1][image_column+1].rgbtRed + image[image_row+1][image_column-1].rgbtRed;
                red_average = my_average(9.0, red_sum);

                green_sum = image[image_row][image_column].rgbtGreen + image[image_row][image_column+1].rgbtGreen + image[image_row-1][image_column].rgbtGreen + image[image_row-1][image_column+1].rgbtGreen + image[image_row-1][image_column-1].rgbtGreen + image[image_row][image_column-1].rgbtGreen + image[image_row+1][image_column].rgbtGreen + image[image_row+1][image_column+1].rgbtGreen + image[image_row+1][image_column-1].rgbtGreen;
                green_average = my_average(9.0, green_sum);

                blue_sum = image[image_row][image_column].rgbtBlue + image[image_row][image_column+1].rgbtBlue + image[image_row-1][image_column].rgbtBlue + image[image_row+1][image_column-1].rgbtBlue + image[image_row-1][image_column-1].rgbtBlue + image[image_row][image_column-1].rgbtBlue + image[image_row+1][image_column].rgbtBlue + image[image_row+1][image_column+1].rgbtBlue + image[image_row+1][image_column-1].rgbtBlue;
                blue_average = my_average(9.0, blue_sum);

                image_copy[image_row][image_column].rgbtRed = red_average;
                image_copy[image_row][image_column].rgbtGreen = green_average;
                image_copy[image_row][image_column].rgbtBlue = blue_average;
            }
            else if (image_column == 0)
            {
                red_sum = image[image_row][image_column].rgbtRed + image[image_row][image_column+1].rgbtRed + image[image_row-1][image_column].rgbtRed + image[image_row-1][image_column+1].rgbtRed + image[image_row+1][image_column].rgbtRed + image[image_row+1][image_column+1].rgbtRed;
                red_average = my_average(6.0, red_sum);

                green_sum = image[image_row][image_column].rgbtGreen + image[image_row][image_column+1].rgbtGreen + image[image_row-1][image_column].rgbtGreen + image[image_row-1][image_column+1].rgbtGreen + image[image_row+1][image_column].rgbtGreen + image[image_row+1][image_column+1].rgbtGreen;
                green_average = my_average(9.0, green_sum);

                blue_sum = image[image_row][image_column].rgbtBlue + image[image_row][image_column+1].rgbtBlue + image[image_row-1][image_column].rgbtBlue + image[image_row-1][image_column+1].rgbtBlue + image[image_row+1][image_column].rgbtBlue + image[image_row+1][image_column+1].rgbtBlue;
                blue_average = my_average(9.0, blue_sum);

                image_copy[image_row][image_column].rgbtRed = red_average;
                image_copy[image_row][image_column].rgbtGreen = green_average;
                image_copy[image_row][image_column].rgbtBlue = blue_average;
            }
            else
            {
                red_sum = image[image_row][image_column].rgbtRed + image[image_row][image_column-1].rgbtRed + image[image_row-1][image_column].rgbtRed + image[image_row-1][image_column-1].rgbtRed + image[image_row+1][image_column].rgbtRed + image[image_row+1][image_column-1].rgbtRed;
                red_average = my_average(6.0, red_sum);

                green_sum = image[image_row][image_column].rgbtGreen + image[image_row][image_column-1].rgbtGreen + image[image_row-1][image_column].rgbtGreen + image[image_row-1][image_column-1].rgbtGreen + image[image_row+1][image_column].rgbtGreen + image[image_row+1][image_column-1].rgbtGreen;
                green_average = my_average(9.0, green_sum);

                blue_sum = image[image_row][image_column].rgbtBlue + image[image_row][image_column-1].rgbtBlue + image[image_row-1][image_column].rgbtBlue + image[image_row][image_column-1].rgbtBlue + image[image_row+1][image_column].rgbtBlue + image[image_row+1][image_column-1].rgbtBlue;
                blue_average = my_average(9.0, blue_sum);

                image_copy[image_row][image_column].rgbtRed = red_average;
                image_copy[image_row][image_column].rgbtGreen = green_average;
                image_copy[image_row][image_column].rgbtBlue = blue_average;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Update:**
I appreciate all help availed me. Now that the codes work, Any suggestions on areas of the current code that can be improved for reusability.

Comment: You did not show the important part. The error complains about a wrong index. You should show where you define your arrays and what limits you are using in your loops.

Comment: If you add `+1` or `-1` to your index variables to handle neighboring pixels, keep in mind to reduce the limits by 1 in each direction.

Comment: _Index out of bounds_ sounds pretty clear to me, and you're even lucky. Usually in C index out of bounds doesn't show any messages but causes "undefined behaviour" (google that term). Anyway you should show us what these line numbers are in your code. And what is `image`? Read this: [mcve]

Comment: "Index 600 out of bounds" pretty much looks as if your image were 600px × 600px and you are on the last row or column 599 and try to access the next element. You need to catch these (literal) edge / corner cases.

Comment: Alternatively to restricting the iteration area, sum only the pixels which are on the image, not off the image, count how many, and divide each RGB sum by that number.

Comment: Your independent snippets are not sufficient. It's not clear what is between the snippets. Please combine them to one continuos piece of code that contains the loops and the code where the error is reported.

Comment: I was actually trying to limit the lines of codes. However, I think its clearer with the full lines code as above.

Comment: Any feedback here? If you need more help, you might tell us which lines in your code are to ones mentioned in the error messages.

Comment: Thanks, @Gerhardh. now I am looking at ways to further break this to increase reusability.

Answer (score 1):

Nasty little typos...

I stripped the lines that could obviously not cause the problem. What's left is a bunch of array accesses.
Then I applied some decent alignment of your lines.

If you do the same things to 3 values of a triple, the lines should look similar.
If you look at it closer, that pattern is broken in 3 places where 1 causes out of bounds accesses while the other 2 only produce wrong results.
Unfortunately I don't know why you got multiple lines reported.

```
for (int image_row = 0; image_row < height; image_row++)
{
    int row_end = image_row - 1;
    int column_end = image_column-1;

    for (int image_column = 0; image_column < width; image_column++)
    {
        if (image_row == 0)
        {   // top
            if (image_column == 0)
            {   // top left
                red_sum   = image[image_row][image_column].rgbtRed   + image[image_row][image_column+1].rgbtRed   + image[image_row+1][image_column].rgbtRed   + image[image_row+1][image_column+1].rgbtRed;
                green_sum = image[image_row][image_column].rgbtGreen + image[image_row][image_column+1].rgbtGreen + image[image_row+1][image_column].rgbtGreen + image[image_row+1][image_column+1].rgbtGreen;
                blue_sum  = image[image_row][image_column].rgbtBlue  + image[image_row][image_column+1].rgbtBlue  + image[image_row+1][image_column].rgbtBlue  + image[image_row+1][image_column+1].rgbtBlue;
            }
            else if (image_column == column_end)
            {   // top right
                red_sum   = image[image_row][column_end].rgbtRed   + image[image_row][column_end-1].rgbtRed   + image[image_row+1][column_end].rgbtRed   + image[image_row+1][column_end-1].rgbtRed;
                green_sum = image[image_row][column_end].rgbtGreen + image[image_row][column_end-1].rgbtGreen + image[image_row+1][column_end].rgbtGreen + image[image_row+1][column_end-1].rgbtGreen;
                blue_sum  = image[image_row][column_end].rgbtBlue  + image[image_row][column_end-1].rgbtBlue  + image[image_row+1][column_end].rgbtBlue  + image[image_row+1][column_end-1].rgbtBlue;
            }
            else
            {   // top middle
                red_sum   = image[image_row][image_column].rgbtRed   + image[image_row][image_column+1].rgbtRed   + image[image_row+1][image_column].rgbtRed   + image[image_row+1][image_column+1].rgbtRed   + image[image_row+1][image_column-1].rgbtRed   + image[image_row][image_column-1].rgbtRed;
                green_sum = image[image_row][image_column].rgbtGreen + image[image_row][image_column+1].rgbtGreen + image[image_row+1][image_column].rgbtGreen + image[image_row+1][image_column+1].rgbtGreen + image[image_row+1][image_column-1].rgbtGreen + image[image_row][image_column-1].rgbtGreen;
                blue_sum  = image[image_row][image_column].rgbtBlue  + image[image_row][image_column+1].rgbtBlue  + image[image_row+1][image_column].rgbtBlue  + image[image_row+1][image_column+1].rgbtBlue  + image[image_row+1][image_column-1].rgbtBlue  + image[image_row][image_column-1].rgbtBlue;
            }
        }
        else if (image_row == row_end)
        {   // bottom
            if (image_column == 0)
            {   // bottom left
                red_sum   = image[image_row][image_column].rgbtRed   + image[image_row][image_column+1].rgbtRed   + image[image_row-1][image_column].rgbtRed   + image[image_row-1][image_column+1].rgbtRed;
                green_sum = image[image_row][image_column].rgbtGreen + image[image_row][image_column+1].rgbtGreen + image[image_row-1][image_column].rgbtGreen + image[image_row-1][image_column+1].rgbtGreen;
                blue_sum  = image[image_row][image_column].rgbtBlue  + image[image_row][image_column+1].rgbtBlue  + image[image_row-1][image_column].rgbtBlue  + image[image_row-1][image_column+1].rgbtBlue;
            }
            else if (image_column == column_end)
            {   // bottom right
                red_sum   = image[image_row][image_column].rgbtRed   + image[image_row][image_column-1].rgbtRed   + image[image_row-1][image_column].rgbtRed   + image[image_row-1][image_column-1].rgbtRed;
                green_sum = image[image_row][image_column].rgbtGreen + image[image_row][image_column-1].rgbtGreen + image[image_row-1][image_column].rgbtGreen + image[image_row-1][image_column-1].rgbtGreen;
                blue_sum  = image[image_row][image_column].rgbtBlue  + image[image_row][image_column-1].rgbtBlue  + image[image_row-1][image_column].rgbtBlue  + image[image_row-1][image_column-1].rgbtBlue;
            }
            else
            {   // bottom middle
                red_sum   = image[image_row][image_column].rgbtRed   + image[image_row][image_column+1].rgbtRed   + image[image_row-1][image_column].rgbtRed   + image[image_row-1][image_column+1].rgbtRed   + image[image_row-1][image_column-1].rgbtRed   + image[image_row][image_column-1].rgbtRed;
                green_sum = image[image_row][image_column].rgbtGreen + image[image_row][image_column+1].rgbtGreen + image[image_row-1][image_column].rgbtGreen + image[image_row-1][image_column+1].rgbtGreen + image[image_row-1][image_column-1].rgbtGreen + image[image_row][image_column-1].rgbtGreen;
                blue_sum  = image[image_row][image_column].rgbtBlue  + image[image_row][image_column+1].rgbtBlue  + image[image_row-1][image_column].rgbtBlue  + image[image_row+1][image_column-1].rgbtBlue  + image[image_row-1][image_column-1].rgbtBlue  + image[image_row][image_column-1].rgbtBlue;
            }                                                                                                                                                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ image_row+1 is out of bounds!
        }
        else
        {   // middle
            if (image_column != 0 && image_column != column_end)
            {   middle middle
                red_sum   = image[image_row][image_column].rgbtRed   + image[image_row][image_column+1].rgbtRed   + image[image_row-1][image_column].rgbtRed   + image[image_row-1][image_column+1].rgbtRed   + image[image_row-1][image_column-1].rgbtRed   + image[image_row][image_column-1].rgbtRed   + image[image_row+1][image_column].rgbtRed   + image[image_row+1][image_column+1].rgbtRed   + image[image_row+1][image_column-1].rgbtRed;
                green_sum = image[image_row][image_column].rgbtGreen + image[image_row][image_column+1].rgbtGreen + image[image_row-1][image_column].rgbtGreen + image[image_row-1][image_column+1].rgbtGreen + image[image_row-1][image_column-1].rgbtGreen + image[image_row][image_column-1].rgbtGreen + image[image_row+1][image_column].rgbtGreen + image[image_row+1][image_column+1].rgbtGreen + image[image_row+1][image_column-1].rgbtGreen;
                blue_sum  = image[image_row][image_column].rgbtBlue  + image[image_row][image_column+1].rgbtBlue  + image[image_row-1][image_column].rgbtBlue  + image[image_row+1][image_column-1].rgbtBlue  + image[image_row-1][image_column-1].rgbtBlue  + image[image_row][image_column-1].rgbtBlue  + image[image_row+1][image_column].rgbtBlue  + image[image_row+1][image_column+1].rgbtBlue  + image[image_row+1][image_column-1].rgbtBlue;
            }                                                                                                                                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ wrong, but not out of bounds
            else if (image_column == 0)
            {   middle left
                red_sum   = image[image_row][image_column].rgbtRed   + image[image_row][image_column+1].rgbtRed   + image[image_row-1][image_column].rgbtRed   + image[image_row-1][image_column+1].rgbtRed   + image[image_row+1][image_column].rgbtRed   + image[image_row+1][image_column+1].rgbtRed;
                green_sum = image[image_row][image_column].rgbtGreen + image[image_row][image_column+1].rgbtGreen + image[image_row-1][image_column].rgbtGreen + image[image_row-1][image_column+1].rgbtGreen + image[image_row+1][image_column].rgbtGreen + image[image_row+1][image_column+1].rgbtGreen;
                blue_sum  = image[image_row][image_column].rgbtBlue  + image[image_row][image_column+1].rgbtBlue  + image[image_row-1][image_column].rgbtBlue  + image[image_row-1][image_column+1].rgbtBlue  + image[image_row+1][image_column].rgbtBlue  + image[image_row+1][image_column+1].rgbtBlue;
            }
            else
            {   middle right
                red_sum   = image[image_row][image_column].rgbtRed   + image[image_row][image_column-1].rgbtRed   + image[image_row-1][image_column].rgbtRed   + image[image_row-1][image_column-1].rgbtRed   + image[image_row+1][image_column].rgbtRed   + image[image_row+1][image_column-1].rgbtRed;
                green_sum = image[image_row][image_column].rgbtGreen + image[image_row][image_column-1].rgbtGreen + image[image_row-1][image_column].rgbtGreen + image[image_row-1][image_column-1].rgbtGreen + image[image_row+1][image_column].rgbtGreen + image[image_row+1][image_column-1].rgbtGreen;
                blue_sum  = image[image_row][image_column].rgbtBlue  + image[image_row][image_column-1].rgbtBlue  + image[image_row-1][image_column].rgbtBlue  + image[image_row][image_column-1].rgbtBlue    + image[image_row+1][image_column].rgbtBlue  + image[image_row+1][image_column-1].rgbtBlue;
            }                                                                                                                                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ wrong, but not out of bounds.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Gerhardh, I did eventually fixed the typos and got my code to work as expected.